# Aeroo for OpenEPR on MacOSX

Tags: python, macos, odoo

I'am using OpenERP under MacOSX for development. I have the problem that pyuno is not avaible in macport. Because of that i can't install the report_aeroo_ooo Modul.

The Software LibreOffice has a the uno packacke inside. But is does work only with the Python Version 3.3 in the LibreOffice 4.0.3.3 Version, because pyuno.so is compiled against this Version.

Has anyone a solution to get aeroo Report running under MacOSX?

Michael

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on Os Lion 10.8 with python 2.7.4 and all openerp dependencies installed installed with homebrew / pip.

I have tried to compile libreoffice version 3.6 (the last version where pyuno depends on python 2) following these tutorials but the build is still failing after lot's of hacks in the configure.in file. The main issue is around the PATH. I can share my hacks and autogen.sh file if you want to try this route.

http://sfarbotka.blogspot.be/2012/10/build-libreoffice-on-osx108-with-xcode45.html
https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Development/BuildingOnMac

This is such a pain knowing that pyuno is only 1500 lines of code.

Alternatively you can try to run Openerp with the bundled python that comes with Openoffice but you need to install/compile lxml for that python version too.

Comment: That is not a good message. I will try this way you explained. But i think i have to go a other way, which was not so pratical for me.